# Update viewport value

Tags: meta-tags

maybe it's a stupid question but I couldn't find any appropriate answer to this question.
I have a website with Drupal 9.4.8
I need to change the default viewport meta, but I couldn't find a way to do it.
I have the Metatag module (which I use to configure my open graph tags) but I can't find any field where I could update the viewport value.
I also read that I need to add this function in a .theme file

```
function MY_THEME_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {
  $viewport = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'name' => 'viewport',
      'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no',
    ),
  );
  $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. The content is added as plain text (and not added at all if I simply add `<?php ?>` tags around the function).

It's probably something really obvious since I can't find any topics mentioning it but I admit I'm a bit lost actually.
Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: This should be possible in Metatag's sub-module "Mobile & UI Adjustments", but you need to enable the sub-module manually.

Comment: Indeed I forgot there was some extra modules with Metatags. Thanks for pointing this out.